# Gene density percentage

Tags: molecular-genetics, genomes

What do we mean when we say that: Haemophilus influenza genome is 85% genic.
How do we measure gene density in percentage, especially for the above-mentioned case?

Answer (score 1):

It means that 85% of its genome is coded for proteins (ORFs). The other 15% not, so these can be regulatory elements, repeats, or other.

You can measure that by measuring the total length of all ORFs, and compare it with the total length of the genome.